Set a lag time for a job to start running once dependency jobs have finished
In Autosys, I would like to set up a lag time for a job to run once all dependency jobs have finished, for example, JobFinal is dependent of jobs Job1, Job2, ... Job10, once all these jobs (Job1-10) have successfully finished, I want JobFinal to run 1 hr later.  Do not get confused with the lookback option s(Job1,HH:MM), this is not what I'm looking for...
Thank you!
Set a timer for a job to run once dependent jobs have successfully completed

can you show what you have attempted ?

We have not tried anything since JobFinal will run once all the dependent jobs have completed successfully.  The main condition is set as: ( s(Job1) & s(Job2) & s(Job3) & ... s(Job10)).  There's no time condition.

show your job entry. have you looked at 'start_mins: ....', sometimes you just need to read the documentation

There are no start time, the dependent jobs run overnite; thus, as previously mentioned, once all the jobs have completed, then my job will run.  The dependent jobs are not mine.  The ask is simple, to add a 'timer' once all the jobs have completed.  If the last job , say Job8, finished at 01:00, then my job will run at 02:00

the fact you've not tried (or asked those managing your autosys instances) is concerning. i have not mentioned 'start_time' , 'start_mins' was , you should refer to the autosys documentation. here's a trivial example you may want to modify to test to see if it suits 'insert_job: jobZZ
job_type: c
condition: s(jobA) & s(jobB) & s(jobC)
start_mins: 15
command: ZZjobScript.sh'
